# How can I get an image URL from HTML codes by Alt in PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument

In fact I want to get an image URL [src] from HTML codes by image alt in PHP, but there is no choice for me.

```
<?php
$html = '
<img border="0" src="/images/image11.jpg" alt="Image11" width="100" height="100" />
<img border="0" src="/images/image22.jpg" alt="Image22" width="100" height="100" />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");

// will return /images/image.jpg
echo $src;
?>
```

This code is just getting src of the image that has alt="Image22".

Comment: Still dint understood your question :(

Comment: i wanna get src of that image has alt="Image22" and its '/images/image22.jpg'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = '<img border="0" src="/images/image11.jpg" alt="Image11" width="100" height="100" /><img border="0" src="/images/image22.jpg" alt="Image22" width="100" height="100" />';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $key => $image){

    if ($image->hasAttributes()){

        if ($image->hasAttribute("src")){

            if ($image->hasAttribute("alt")){

                $alt = $image->getAttribute("alt");

                if ($alt == 'Image22'){

                    $src = $image->getAttribute("src");

                    echo "<br>" . $src . "<br>";

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = '
<img border="0" src="/images/image11.jpg" alt="Image11" width="100" height="100" />
<img border="0" src="/images/image22.jpg" alt="Image22" width="100" height="100" />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$res = $xpath->query('//img');
foreach($res as $img) {

    echo $img->getAttribute('alt');
}


?>
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. like the top answer i wanna a place to typing alt name and getting src. and turkmusun?

Comment: Evet Türküm. Your is img file echo $img->getAttribute('src'); Ok.